# Convert RGB to HSV

Tags: image, image-processing, octave

i want to convert RGB values to HSV values . But if I devide 9 by 28, octave calculate 0. Can anyone explain me the reason??

```
function [hsv] = RGBtoHSV()
    im = imread('picture.png'); 
    R = im(:,:,1); 
    G = im(:,:,2); 
    B = im(:,:,3);

    len = length(R); % R, G, B should have the same length
    for i = 1:len
        MAX = max([R(i),G(i),B(i)]);
        MIN = min([R(i),G(i),B(i)]);
        S = 0;
        if MAX == MIN
            H = 0;
        elseif MAX == R(i)
            disp(G(i) - B(i)); % 9 
            disp(MAX - MIN);  % 28
            H = 0.6 * ( 0 + ( (G(i) - B(i)) / MAX - MIN) ); % 0
            disp(H) % why i get 0 if try to calculate ( 0 + ( (G(i) - B(i)) / MAX - MIN)?
        ....
            end
        return;
    end
endfunction

RGBtoHSV()
```

Chris :D

Comment: Does Octave have different types for integer (whole) numbers and real (floating point) numbers? `9/28 = 0` is true when working with integers.

Comment: no `disp(9/28)`; works. solution : `0.32143`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must cast the image into `Double` by doing:

```
im = double(imread('picture.png'));
```

This will solve your issues which happens since the image is type `UINT8`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Octave's builtin rgb2hsv function instead of writing your own.

```
im_rgb = imread ("picture.png"); 
im_hsv = rgb2hsv (im_rgb);
```

If this is an exercise, then I'd suggest you look at its source, enter `type rgb2hsv` at the Octave prompt, and see how its implemented.